# Is it good practice to create an API to handle calls to multiple APIs for integration

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-2.1

Brief overview, I am working with Visual Studio 2017 and .Net Core 2.1. I am about to begin development on a website which will handle integrating 3 existing pieces of software which our company uses.

I have created WCF services already for use by some of the applications I have developed, but for this project, there are multiple APIs which I will be utilizing. It's quite possible that I may need to use these APIs in other projects down the road.

I apologize if this is an opinionated question, but here it goes, do you think it is good design to develop one central API which wraps all the calls to the integrated system APIs? My thoughts were that in this way, I only have to write the code once for making the desired API calls and I can then add to this API as I see fit moving forward, ie. another system API is needed.

Please feel free to give advice, I am still learning and appreciate constructive advice. I am using this to get started on building my API using .Net Core 2.1, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Try [softwareengineering.se] instead of [so], that would be a better fit.

Comment: @Igor Ok, thank you. Is there a way to move this question from here to there?

Comment: See [How do I move my own question to another Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85041/386424)

Comment: @Igor Thank you. I will read that now.

Answer (score 0):

If the APIs are related then yes it does make sense to create a single assembly to call those for you and deal with the responses. You'd then consume that assembly in all your other apps.

However, if the APIs are completely different and require different set ups, then it may make more sense to create an assembly wrapper for each to keep the concerns separate.

You don't want to confuse the APIs. If anyone was to look at your code or assembly, they should be able to say that it relates to what it describes and not have to guess.

Comment: Thank you for the input, even though the integrated APIs may be different, I figured each Controller in the API I would build could be responsible for it's own integrated API, thus the naming convention should make that pretty clear to any other developer.